# Pass variable model type to C# function in MVC to simplfy code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a bunch of model update routines that only vary with the model passed, for example:

```
public void UpdateAccount(AccountViewModel model)
{
    var _currentData = (from data in db.Accounts
                         where data.AccountId == model.AccountId
                         select data).Single();
    Mapper.Map(model, _currentData);
    Save();
}
```

I have a bunch of similar functions, where the model passed varies along with the data key. Can this be made more generic?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to make each of your models implement the same interface:

```
interface IViewModel
{
    int AccountId { get; }
}

class AccountViewModel : IViewModel
{
    ...
}
```

And then you can pass any viewmodel implementing this interface to your `UpdateAccount` method:

```
public void UpdateAccount(IViewModel model)
{
    var _currentData = (from data in db.Accounts
                        where data.AccountId == model.AccountId
                        select data).Single();
    Mapper.Map(model, _currentData);
    Save();

}
```

Or you could define it as:

```
public void UpdateAccount<TViewModel>(TViewModel model) 
    where TViewModel: IViewModel { ... }
```

However, this means you will also have to change the definition of `Mapper.Map(...)` method to accept your new interface: `Mapper.Map(IViewModel model, ...)`.

**Edit**: Just saw each viewmodel has a different *data key* (property?), perhaps this is a better solution:

```
public void UpdateAccount<T>(T model, Func<T, int> dataKeySelector)
{
    var _currentData = (from data in db.Accounts
                        where data.AccountID == dataKeySelector(model)
                        select data).Single();
    Mapper.Map(model, _currentData);
    Save();
}
```

Which can be called by `UpdateAccount(model, m => m.AccountID);`.

Hope this helps.